# How can I pass Jenkins Secret File to the Groovy Script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a secret file that basically contains some metadata.I am using "withCredentials" block to read that file into local variable as:

```
stage('fetch')
   {
   steps{
       withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secret.json', variable: 'metadata')]) {
           script{
     def rootDir = pwd()
    def exampleModule = load "${rootDir}/test.groovy"
    def res=exampleModule.process(${metadata})
    sh 'echo $res'
           }
     }
    }
   }
```

But the metadata is coming as masked to the exampleModule's getData.How can I pass it is unmasked form?

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt and and print out the secret value

```
println hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("<Your masked data>")
```

If you are using secretbytes which is your case you need to do:

```
println(new String(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SecretBytes.fromString("{<Your secretbytesmask>}").getPlainData(), "ASCII"))
```

To know the secret bytes you should open `credentials.xml` file present in your JenkinsHome directory and copy the secretbytes as shown:
[image]
Note: You would need to approve the script if running from jenkins pipeline as you will get a below message in console:
[image]
You need to click and approve this script and once approved, you will be able to see the unmasked contents.

Comment: I have updated code with complete details.Where should I use this?In exampleModule.process? Is it possible to do in pipeline itself?

Comment: @user124 this was an example to show you how you can decrypt. You can use             ```def res=exampleModule.process(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("${metadata}"))```

Comment: it did not work because the static method are not allowed in script. org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod hudson.util.Secret decrypt java.lang.String
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:189)
Is there a way around?

Comment: @user124 The credentials are only masked inside the withCredentials block. If you assign them to a variable defined outside the block and then print that variable outside the block, no masking is applied.I have added in answer

Comment: the metadata variable in which teamdetails will be loaded will be shell variable right? Can we use it like the way you told?For me,it just print the name of file

Comment: @user124 sorry that works for everything else, except file credential. I have added the option to access secret bytes and get unmasked data. If the script is approved then it works. I got the results